# calculate the sum of 5 numbers, knowing the product of their values minus 4

Tags: systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations

$a,b,c,d$ and $e$ are five different integers. If $(4-a)(4-b)(4-c)(4-d)(4-e)=12$, then calculate $a+b+c+d+e$.

Comment: Even if you restrict the numbers to integers ${2,2,3,3,1}$ and ${0,3,3,3,1}$ gives two different results. I guess maybe the question means "positive integers"?

Comment: what has been tried ?

Comment: Are $a$,$b$,$c$,$d$ and $e$ real or integers? Are they positive or negative? You should always post the full princlement statement along with what you've tried so far.

Comment: the numbers are different integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution: $12$ can be expressed as a product of five integers only as $1\times(-1)\times2\times(-2)\times3 =12$, the $a-4=1, b-4=-1, c-4=2, d-4=-2$ and $e-4=3$. we deduce from that $a+b+c+d+e=23$.